# Angular proxy config not having any effect in google cloud API Engine

Tags: angular, google-cloud-platform, proxy, backend

I have an angular app running on http://localhost:4200/ and a spring boot back-end running on http://localhost:8080/
In my frontend app in src folder I've created a proxy.config.json file which looks like this:

```
{
"/server": {
   "target": "http://localhost:8080",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/server" : ""
    }
  }
}
```

I've added the proxy to package.json as bellow:

"start": "ng serve --proxy-config src/proxy.conf.json",

So, each time a request that start with /server/api/... is made, that will be converted to
http://localhost:8080/api/...

This IS WORKING OK on my local machine.

Next, I've deployed my backend app to google cloud app engine and all went ok, the backend is up and running on a public google cloud adress.
Then, in my frontend app I've changed the "target" parameter to point to the public cloud address and test my frontend app again (locally) and all went ok.

Next, I've built and deployed my frontend app to a new google cloud app engine.
Now I have both apps running and two google cloud app engine at two different .com addresses.

However, the frontend app does not connect with the backend app anymore. The proxy configuration has NO effect and the /server does not get converted to point to the backend public address.

I've added my src/proxy.conf.json into angulat.json file under:

```
"serve": {
          "builder": "@...",
          "configurations": {
            "options": {
              "browserTarget": "...",
              "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
            },
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "...",
              "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
            },
```

rebuild, re-deploy, still no effect.

I've added in my app.modules.ts the

```
{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}
```

rebuild, redeploy, still no effect, except that indeed the # is not present in my URL.

Are there other configurations I need to do for getting the proxy conversion to work in google cloud app engine?